# Is there a way to open windows app maximized?

Tags: windows, windows-10, resolution

for starter, I already know the shortcut trick which doesn't work for each file when opening them by double clicking.

is there universal way to open any application on Windows machine in maximized window?

Some apps I use need to change the window size while using it. and next time I reopen the app, it opens it with same size and position of screen.

Comment: short answer: no. There is no universal way. Its up to apps to respect it. Some have their own option, and some don't even support it. If you want one place to do this all, use a third-party app that can control this behavior for other apps.

Answer (score 0):

General remarks :

- Many applications use the <kbd>F11</kbd> key to maximize to full-screen
- Closing an application by clicking on the X button on the bar and while
  holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key may make Windows remember its closing
  window size and position
- The free
  [Maximize Always](https://softpcapps.com/maximize-always/)
  can keep a list of applications that it forces to always open in
  maximized mode.

**Using AutoHotKey**

As Windows doesn't have an official method for opening an application
from Explorer in maximized mode, you may add this feature yourself
using the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will on pressing
<kbd>F12</kbd>
run the currently-selected item in maximized mode:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
F12::
    item := Explorer_GetSelection()
    Run, % item,,Max
    Return

Explorer_GetSelection(hwnd="") {
    hwnd := hwnd ? hwnd : WinExist("A")
    WinGetClass class, ahk_id %hwnd%
    if (class="CabinetWClass" or class="ExploreWClass" or class="Progman")
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
            if (window.hwnd==hwnd)
    sel := window.Document.SelectedItems
    for item in sel
    ToReturn .= item.path "`n"
    return Trim(ToReturn,"`n")
}
```

This script is not adapted to running multiple programs, so ensure that
only one item is selected.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)